# facebook app autoupdate stoping

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, facebook, application-autoupdate

I need to stop auto updating Facebook app and tried [these steps](https://www.facebook.com/help/456186367793974).

But still Facebook app is auto updating. After updating and installing the app, it is shown "Facebook app is successfully updated" message in my android phone.

Additional info.

Phone model : HTC Desire 630

OS : Android M

So can I stop auto updating the Facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

For one, I can't open the link. Did you turn off auto-updating in the Play Store settings?
Most apps will auto-update through the Play Store. Turn that off and it shouldn't update anymore.

Comment: I already turn off auto update through play store.